Ssquezepy CWT graphics not coinciding with PSD (Wrong labels?)
I am trying to visualize a spectrogram with ssq_cwtfrom ssqueezepy in Python. The time series comes from an RR file, interpolated and equidistantly resampled at 6Hz. I'm using the following code:
fs = 6
Tx, Wx, ssq_freqs, scales = ssq_cwt(rr_signal, fs=fs, wavelet='morlet')
wavelet = Wavelet(wavelet='morlet')
frequencies = scale_to_freq(scales, wavelet, len(rr_signal), fs=fs)
im = ax.imshow(np.abs(Wx), aspect='auto', extent=[time[0], time[-1], frequencies[-1], frequencies[0]])

I'm getting the following graphic:

I noticed the most intense band is around 1Hz, which is not physiologically plausible, so I decided to look at a PSD done with Fast Fourier Transform, getting a peak at 0.1Hz (which is physiologically plausible):

To get more insight, I reduced my Wavelet matrix to 1 dimension in the vertical and horizontal axis, this should get something like PSD, if done correctly. I also plotted a red dot in the most intense frequency:
average_1_dim = np.mean(np.abs(Wx), axis=1)
plt.plot(frequencies, average_1_dim)
max_value = np.max(average_1_dim)
max_index = np.where(average_1_dim == max_value)
plt.plot(frequencies[max_index], max_value, 'ro')


This projection of the first axis gave me a similar PSD to the FFT, so I can confirm the Wx matrix seems correct (the red dot is at 0.106).
I flipped the axis and took a screenshot to better show the discrepancy:

My only question is why is the most powerful band (around 1Hz) not coinciding with my CWT projection at 1Hz? Also, I can see this powerful band at ~1Hz in the CWT Spectrogram but in both PSD and CWT projection I see no peak at that point, conversely, it is close to 0.
I think it is a problem with scale or axis, but after some tweaking, I seem unable to find it. I checked this, however, it seems the yticks argument is now deprecated and I should use the extent argument, and I think I'm using it correctly.
Progress
It seems an approach by importing imshow from ssqueezepy yields a rather good spectrogram, which seems to respect my PSD and CWT projected.
from ssqueezepy import imshow
imshow(np.abs(Wx), aspect='auto', cmap='ocean', xticks=time, yticks=ssq_freqs)


Now the issue is Y axis doesn't have equidistant ticks, any idea on how could I fix it?
